# EntitySQL -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am getting this error when I try to do an insert on a column that is a foreign key. Here is how I am assigning the value

```
var at = MvcApplication1.Entity.alttitles.Createalttitles(0, altTitleText);
        at.question.question_id = questionid;   //Error here
        at.userinfo.user_userid = _AuthorID;    //Error here
        context.AddToalttitles(at);
        res = context.SaveChanges();
```

When I made the question_id and the userid a foreign key I started getting this error. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Most likely, the "question" is a referenced entity, right? Those are **not** included by default in your query - you'll need to specifically either include them in your first query</strike>

```
var at = MvcApplication1.Entity.alttitles
              .Createalttitles(0, altTitleText)
              .Include("question");
```

Is "question" a 1:1 or 1:n navigation property? In the 1:n case, you can check the "question" property directly:

```
if(!at.question.IsLoaded)
{
   at.question.Load();

   ....
}
```

In a 1:1 navigation property case, you probably have a "QuestionReference" property as well:

```
if(!at.QuestionReference.IsLoaded)
{
   at.QuestionReference.Load();

   ....
}
```

Marc

Comment: Your examples are backwards. "Reference" is for 1:1.

Comment: oops - thanks for pointing that out! Haven't been using it much lately (waiting for EF4), so my memory begins to slip :-)

Comment: Createalttitles is a entity sql create function to insert new rows in the database. It does not have an Include option in intelisense

Comment: ah okay, I didn't know if it was returning a IQueryable<T> interface or not; in that case, do any of the other ideas help? I am almost certain this is the root cause of the problem - the "question" property is not being populated automatically (since EF does not do that)

Comment: OK..No problem..I will try this as soon as I get home..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check if at is not null before assigning its properties?